# malloc - Hardfault - Keil uVision

Tags: struct, malloc, keil, circular-buffer

I am using 72kB Flash with 16kB RAM Controller. IDE : Keil uVision v5.29 IDE.

I'm creating a circular buffer, which is a pointer to structure.

The malloc is  creating a hardfault. the code:

```
/*** Header File *****/


typedef struct circular_structbuf_t circular_structbuf_t;

typedef circular_structbuf_t* scbuf_handle_t;

/****** C file *****/
struct main_struct
{
    int data;
    char char_data;
}

struct circular_structbuf_t
{
    struct  main_struct st_array[128];
    uint8_t st_head;
    uint8_t st_tail;
    uint8_t st_max; //of the buffer
    bool st_full;
};


scbuf_handle_t circular_structbuf_init(scbuf_handle_t scbuf, size_t size)
{
    scbuf = malloc(sizeof(circular_structbuf_t));                       // Causes Hardfault
    scbuf->st_max = size;
    circular_structbuf_reset(scbuf);
    return scbuf;
}


/** Main File ***/
scbuf_handle_t p_cbuf;


int main(void)
{
    p_cbuf=circular_structbuf_init(p_cbuf,50);
    
}
```

While debugging, the address to `p_cbuf` is assigned as `0x0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your target system has **very** little RAM. It is possible that `malloc()` is unable to meet the allocation request, but you do not test for `malloc()` failure. The *hard fault* may be caused by your dereferencing a null pointer at `scbuf->st_max = size;`.

Try reducing the structure size, with a lower number of entries in `st_array`, check if `malloc()` returns `NULL` and signal this error using whatever means of communication you have. You might also need to adjust the stack size and the heap size.

Note also these remarks:

- if `circular_structbuf_init` always allocates a new structure, it should not take `scbuf` as an argument.
- you could reduce the memory footprint of this structure using a flexible array: the `st_array` is moved at the end of the structure and only enough space for the head and the actual number of elements is allocated.

Here is a modified version:

```c
/*** Header File *****/

typedef struct circular_structbuf_t circular_structbuf_t;

typedef circular_structbuf_t *scbuf_handle_t;

/****** C file *****/

struct main_struct {
    int data;
    char char_data;  // if `int` is aligned, there will be some padding after this field
};

struct circular_structbuf_t {
    uint8_t st_head;
    uint8_t st_tail;
    uint8_t st_max; // of the buffer
    bool st_full;   // type bool is assumed to be a `uint8_t`
    struct main_struct st_array[];  // flexible array syntax
};

scbuf_handle_t circular_structbuf_init(size_t size) {
    scbuf_handle_t scbuf; 
    scbuf = malloc(sizeof(circular_structbuf_t) + size * sizeof(struct main_struct));
    if (scbuf) {
        scbuf->st_max = size;       
        circular_structbuf_reset(scbuf);
    }
    return scbuf;
}

/** Main File ***/

scbuf_handle_t p_cbuf;

int main(void) {
    p_cbuf = circular_structbuf_init(50);
    if (p_cbuf == NULL) {
        /* report the error */
    }
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

If your compiler does not support flexible arrays, you can define `st_array` as

```
struct main_struct st_array[0];
```

If this alternative is also rejected by the compiler, use `1` for the defined size.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I obviously didnt get a hardfault at 

`scbuf = malloc(sizeof(circular_structbuf_t));`

But instead at dereferncing in :

`circular_structbuf_reset(scbuf);` 
which assigns value 0 to the members `st_head` and `st_tail` .

Increased the Heap size and Stack size 0x800.

This has worked now, avoiding the hardfault. but will there be any future issues?

Comment: @ATHMESHANDROID: I updated the answer with more remarks and suggestions

Comment: thank you very much. I'll modify code based on this and will review.